# Can't install gem -- install-tools

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, pg

I am trying to install the `pg` gem in OSX Yosemite beta. It's giving me an error `You have to install development tools first.` So I try `xcode-select --install` and it tells me they are already installed:

`xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Anyone have any idea what's up? Is it because I'm using RVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this problem has to do with a recent update of XCode. After a XCode update you need to do the following steps:

1. Open Xcode and accept the license agreement
2. Reinstall the Command Line Tools.

The second step seems to depend on your OS versions. If `xcode-select --install` does not work try to start the `Install Command Line Developer Tools` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

After reinstalling the Command Line Tools try to rerun `bundle install`.

Comment: @spickermann-- nailed it! Thank you! Never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues, you can accept Xcode terms from terminal.

I believe the command is:

```
sudo xcrun cc
```

And follow on screen directions.